# Should "Weekly Newsletter" mail include (very) old posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, email, newsletter

I received my "Stack Overflow Weekly Newsletter", and noticed that one of the "Greatest hits from previous weeks" is a pretty much old post (Apr 7 '11) that got [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java/35834484#35834484) 9 days ago:

[image: old post]

Here's [the (old) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java).

### My suggestion

Can we get more recent questions instead of (very) old ones, even if they are less popular? I'm not sure how useful or relevant a question from 5 years ago that popped up only because a tiny edit was made.

Comment: Apparently.  Afaict there was only one "greatest hit" last week.  It was put on hold as "too broad" :)  Maybe you should ask them to feature "most popular" instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually I got [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div?newsletter=1&nlcode=226254%7c4e77) too. It's old, but was edited.. so it's great :)